# Using smart view in OBIEE 12C

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, office-addins, obiee, smartview

I was going to use smart view (which is downloaded, installed and added as a tab to Microsoft's products ex. Execl) and connect it to OBIEE 12.2.1.4. So I have downloaded 11.1.2.5 version.

[image]

According to my searching on the internet, I have found that in order to create a private connection, it should be done be selecting 'Oracle BI EE' connection provider, whilst **I have not this option now**. As a result, I fail to connect to OBIEE. I mean like below image:

[image]

As an additional INFO, I have found this URL, http://epmstream.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-set-up-obiee-access-through.html , which had a same problem and solved. But in my case, I couldn't unfortunately download 11.1.2.2.310 version

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing much info, but with any fresh installation of SmartView you just click SmartView -> Panel -> Private Connection and then at the very bottom "Create new connection".

There probably was something messed up on the Windows/Excel side during install (it's Windows after all...) or you had some Office product running whle installing SmartView.

You have to close all Office products completely, then find JBIPSProviderInstaller.svext on your file system (Normally C:\Oracle\SmartView). Right-click it -> Open With -> Oracle Smart View for Office.

You should get a message saying it's installed.

Comment: **what I did:**
As  you have mentioned, I clicked **(1-)** SmartView -> **(2-)** Panel -> **(3-)** Private Connection -> **(4-)** Create new connection (which is at the left bottom corner).
Then, **(5-)** a window is displayed (something like the last attached image in the answer body but) with just one option, means "Smart View HTTP Provider". **(6-)** By clicking this one, another window is showed to enter a connection URL.

Comment: **In the point, I have two questions:**
**First:** In almost more than 95 percent of available articles on the internet in the regard to my problem, the window which is presented in step number 5, is exactly like the attached image in question with two options (this image belongs to the mentioned URL in the question body), that they selected "Oracle BI EE" option and so everything went well. While I have not this option. I do not why !
**Second:** In the step number 6, what should I expected to write?, I mean, I entered `http://IP:Port/analytics/jbips/`, according to articles, but it failed.

Comment: I forgot to say that in excel, it was just added smart view tab, and there is not any Oracle BI tab

Comment: There never is an OBIEE "tab". The option is in the connection. I'll update the main response.

Comment: Actually yes, first there is no tab named OBIEE. A tab named Oracle BI will created when connection is established and we are going to design a view

Comment: Yesss, this is the definite solution. It is worth mentioning that based on Oracle support document, the cause of this issue is undetermined. Thanks

Comment: Actually what I've typed out here is something that's documented very clearly on Oracle Support.

Comment: Yes, I have studied it too. Thanks again for your answering.